# How to get all files from a folder and his subfolders?

Tags: u-sql

Imagine this files paths:

1. */root/subfolder/filename.csv*
2. */root/subfolder/subfolder2/filename2.csv*

Can I extract data from "filename.csv" and "filename2.csv" without explicitly write their paths?

I want to do something like:

```
@var = EXTRACT column FROM "/root/{*}.csv" USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
```

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature (a Kleene-* like recursive folder navigation) is not yet available in filesets, but is on our long term roadmap. Please file/upvote for this feature at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

The current work-around is to have one step wild card `EXTRACT`s for each level you expect to encounter and then UNION ALL them together. E.g.,

```
 @d1 = EXTRACT ... FROM "/fixpath/{*}" USING ... ;
 @d2 = EXTRACT ... FROM "/fixpath/{*}/{*}" USING ...;
 @d3 = EXTRACT ... FROM "/fixpath/{*}/{*}/{*}" USING ...;
 ....

 @data = 
   SELECT * FROM @d1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM @d2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM @d3 UNION ALL ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! The formatting is almost exactly what you thought it would be. It's done through filesets in U-SQL, and they allow you to search entire directories of folders and also extract information from the path. You define wildcard characters of your choice anywhere in the folder path, and then save that character as a virtual column in your extract statement.

```
DECLARE @file_set_path string = "/Samples/Data/AmbulanceData/vehicle{vid}_{date:MM}{date:dd}{date:yyyy}.csv";

@data = 
EXTRACT vehicle_id int, 
        entry_id long, 
        event_date DateTime, 
        latitude float, 
        longitude float, 
        speed int, 
        direction string, 
        trip_id int?, 
        vid int,  // virtual file set column
        date DateTime // virtual file set column
FROM @file_set_path
USING Extractors.Csv();
```

Notice the regular wild card character in the path {vid}, and how it's saved in the extract statement as a new column with the same name (that you can then use to filter your query).  The date virtual column is a special feature of filesets that allows you to automatically bundle dates in filesets into a single DateTime object.

Filesets also work in directory paths the same way - you could have a set of subfolders divided by date and version, and use "/Samples/{date:yyyy}/{date:MM}/{date:dd}/{type}/RCV_{vid}.csv" and store the virtual columns identically as above.

Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Hi @mabasile_MSFT, thanks for your answer but it's not what I want. In this way you have to know all folder schemas and I don't know that. That's why I was trying something like "/root/{*}.csv". The goal is: Get all 'csv' files that exist under root folder and its sub-folders.